# MariaDB and phpMyAdmin - Unable to authenticate with ed25519

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

By the official MariaDB doc, they recommend using [the ed25519 authentication plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-ed25519/) instead of the default, weak, authentication.

So far so good. I followed the guide but am now stuck with authenticating inside phpmyadmin. I get following error:
[image]

A quick web-search says that most authentication plugins are not supported yet. Therefore, the only solution is to use the old weak `mysql_native_password`.

Is there now another way, since MariaDB recommends ed25519 but only native password is generally supported?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/385378/mysql-connect-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-clien

Answer (score 2):

Without any details about how you arrived at that problem, I can't really be sure if [my problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1202462/28965) is the same as yours.

But if this is still relevant to you, and you have root access to the server hosting your phpMyAdmin, try:

```
apt install libmariadbclient18
```

It looks like the default `mariadb-client` doesn't come with the plugin needed to authenticate as ed25519. `libmariadbclient18` provided a version which worked in my case.

*Edit: I've just noticed you gave [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/954684/135566) to someone else already but suggested it didn't help you. I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else.*