# How do I authenticate with ed25519 using the MariaDB client?

Tags: mysql, authentication, mariadb

Whilst launching [MariaDB via Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) using `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` I was prompted to run `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation`. This makes sense but ([like others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24270733/594137)) I prefer configuring things non-interactively so started looking into the SQL commands this script runs. [One of the comments](http://disq.us/p/26cgdtx) to [this article](https://bertvv.github.io/notes-to-self/2015/11/16/automating-mysql_secure_installation/) includes the following SQL:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'root';
```

Which in turn led me to find MariaDB [advises](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-mysql_native_password/) using `ed25519` instead of `mysql_native_password`.

So I added the following to my `.cnf` which is provided to the Docker container and restarted the container.

```
[mariadb]
plugin_load_add=auth_ed25519
```

Then I connected with the `mysql` client (from `apt install mariadb-client`) and executed:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED VIA ed25519 USING PASSWORD('secret');
MariaDB [(none)]> \q
```

Then I attempted to reconnect and receive the following error:

```
$ mysql --protocol=tcp --user=root -psecret
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'client_ed25519' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/client_ed25519.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.43-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Why am I receiving that error and how I can enable ed25519 authentication with the MariaDB client?

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've managed to fix the problem with 10.1 changed 10.3 for my installation.

Answer (score 2):

The shared library seems to exist within the container ([mariadb:10.4](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb)), but not in the Ubuntu 18.04 apt package(s) for `mariadb-client`.

```
find / -iregex '.*ed25519.so'
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5607d87792ae2f4989aa5a72188f1c47f86b19ce42a92139b50b697a39ecb798/diff/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_ed25519.so
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5607d87792ae2f4989aa5a72188f1c47f86b19ce42a92139b50b697a39ecb798/diff/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/client_ed25519.so
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/38451e628c3926f60d07e9852332f751486471b4a008d9a1b1e7f04d30b2eba1/merged/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/auth_ed25519.so
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/38451e628c3926f60d07e9852332f751486471b4a008d9a1b1e7f04d30b2eba1/merged/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/client_ed25519.so
```

The apt package for `mariadb-server` *does* include the `auth_ed25519.so`, but no sign of its partner in the `mariadb-client` package (or any of its dependencies).

```
$ apt-file list mariadb-server-10.1 | grep ed25519.so
mariadb-server-10.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/auth_ed25519.so
$ dpkg --listfiles mariadb-client-10.1 mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-common | grep ed25519.so
$
```

The only place I can locate that file is in a package called `libmariadbclient18` which only contains libraries.

```
$ apt-file find client_ed25519.so
libmariadbclient18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/client_ed25519.so
$ apt-file list libmariadbclient18
libmariadbclient18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so.18
libmariadbclient18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmariadbclient.so.18.0.0
libmariadbclient18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/client_ed25519.so
libmariadbclient18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/dialog.so
libmariadbclient18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/disks.so
libmariadbclient18: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb18/plugin/mysql_clear_password.so
libmariadbclient18: /usr/share/doc/libmariadbclient18/changelog.Debian.gz
libmariadbclient18: /usr/share/doc/libmariadbclient18/copyright
```

After installing the library, the connection succeeds.

```
$ apt install libmariadbclient18
$ mysql --protocol=tcp --user=root -psecret
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 17
Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

I found this not a particularly obvious sequence of problems so thought I would leave this here in case others or my-future-self need it. It probably would be helpful to be named something like `mariadb-plugins` or at least be `Suggested` by `mariadb-client`.

Comment: I have suggested this is fixed ([mariadb-10.1/+bug/1859341](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.1/+bug/1859341))